# How to remove dead children from the array in perl Parallel::ForkManager?

Tags: arrays, perl, fork, daemon

I was advised to use `Parallel::ForkManager` to demonize. As you can see, I use the `run` for demonization.

```
sub run {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $pfm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($self);
    while(1) {
       $pfm->run_on_wait( sub {
        #some code here
    },sleep(0.0001));
    my $pid = $pfm->start;
        if ($pid != 0) {
            # Parent process
            push @childs, $pid;
            sleep 1;
            next;
        }
        # Child process; do some work
        $self = &doWork();
        # Worker finished, clean up the $pfm instance
        $pfm->finish();

    }
}
```

All children PIDs are stored in an array `@childs`, if one of them dies, the cycle allow to restore  the desired number of children, but older(dead) PIDs are in the array, how to remove them? And will the new array is visible in the code that located in `run_on_wait`.

Comment: Why are you passing `$self` into Parallel::ForkManager? And what are you trying to accomplish with your `@childs`?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to build the array in the first place. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: pids in `@childs` uses for `update` in dbi. `doWork()` check database for this pids. 

`$self` used only for set max number of childs, it's doesnt matter, i can use static variable.

Comment: Very strange thing to do - `$self` is usually used to denote object oriented code.

Comment: it's my bad, this method based on example, who based for oop

Comment: I also think `run_on_wait` doesn't do what you think it does. It makes no sense to redefine it every iteration of your `while` loop, nor does passing `sleep` into it as a parameter.

Comment: i use `run_on_wait` because I need to script worked like a demon, as well as his children and do some operations with database. I have not found a better solution for this except as a `run_on_wait`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misusing `Parallel::ForkManager`.

What it does/is for, is to allow you to automatically limit a number of processes.

You specify the limit when calling the constructor (`new`).

E.g.:

```
my $pfm = Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( $n_concurrent );
```

Usually `$self` is used to denote object oriented calls.

The `run_on_wait` method is quite relevant to what you're doing, so it would help if you showed it. But I think you're misunderstanding what it's for, because you're redefining it every iteration of a `while` loop.

`run_on_wait $code, [$period]
You can define a subroutine which is called when the child process needs to wait for the startup. If $period is not defined, then one call is done per child. If $period is defined, then $code is called periodically and the module waits for $period seconds between the two calls. Note, $period can be fractional number also. The exact "$period seconds" is not guaranteed, signals can shorten and the process scheduler can make it longer (on busy systems).`

But it's really not intended to have an embedded `sleep` in it. It's supposed to include a wait delay, and it'll run the 'wait' code is called.

But it also doesn't really make sense to redefine this each iteration of your while loop. It's also unclear what you're using `@childs` for in the first place - why do you need to maintain a list of pids at all - `Parallel::ForkManager` is tracking numbers and handling joining/waiting for you.

If you need to track your children for some other reason - then you might find it more useful to use the 'start' and 'finish' mechanisms.

`start [ $process_identifier ]
This method does the fork. It returns the pid of the child process for the parent, and 0 for the child process. If the $processes parameter for the constructor is 0 then, assuming you're in the child process, $pm->start simply returns 0.`

`An optional $process_identifier can be provided to this method... It is used by the "run_on_finish" callback (see CALLBACKS) for identifying the finished process.`

Comment: The code that is located in `run_on_wait` must be performed continuously (infinite loop). It implements a database operation (with two bases). PIDs of child processes used in this code. `doWork()` method from another script who must work like daemon(check for PIDs who located in database and others operations).

Comment: You still don't need to redefine the sub each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Turn it into a hash. Insert pid as hash key, then use `delete`.

Comment: The problem is not how to remove from the array, but how to determine which of the PIDs is dead.

And as I understood the method `run_on_wait` runs when the start first child. How to run it when the desired number of children running?

Comment: `run_on_finish` runs when a process finishes. You can embed an identity when you start the process.

Comment: process never finishes, they must work in infinite loop.